# I would like to execute regular function in async way

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Consider this sample (say this is module)

```
function Calculator(value){
    return {
        add: function(value2){
            return: {
                value: function(){
                    return value + value2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a class, and requires an argument when initialization, sample usage:

```
var Calculator = require('calculator_app_module');
var myCalc = new Calculator(1); // initialized with 1

myCalc.add(2).value(); //  === 3;
```

Which is obviously expected, what i want is to execute `add` function in async way, just like that

```
var Calculator = require('calculator_app_module');
var myCalc = new Calculator(1); // initialized with 1

myCalc.add(2).value() ==== 3  // this executes in 2secs (async)
                              // and then returns result
```

I would like to patch **Calculator.add** method so that it can work with async

```
function patch(module){ //module is Calculator class
    var oldAdd = Calculator.add;
    Calculator.add = function(){
        // some magic
        // trigger event or whatever
        oldAdd.apply(Calculator, arguments);
    }
}
```

**`INDEX.JS`**

```
var Calculator = require('calculator_app_module');
var calc = new Calculator(1);

calc.add(2).value() === 3;     // equalize within 2 seconds
                               // after async call is done
calc.add(2).value().equal(3);  // also legit
```

The problem is that `calc.add(n)` returns new function `value` which is undefined in async call, is there a way to get the calling fn of `add` and call it back when result comes

### update

Prior to **@Zohaib Ijaz** answer, you cannot modify content/logic of package, only extend/patch, Package must return same API but in promise way, no code breaking

```
calc.add(2).value() === 3;    // sync code
calc.add(2).value() === 3;    // async code
calc.add(2).value().equal(3); // async code
```

How to achieve

### update

According to **@Zohaib Ijaz** comment, this also legit

```
myCalc.add(2).value().equal(3); //async
```

Point is in converting sync to async without breaking package, but extending the outcome

Comment: Hint: `Calculator.add` doesn't exist.  You have to _call_ `Calculator` to get hold of an object with an `add` function.

Comment: but according to your Calculator class, there is no such async. `calc.add(2).value() === 3;` line will be executed once, how you can say that `equalize within 2 seconds`. Can you explain more

Comment: @JamesThorpe this was a generic idea, to patch sync package into async package, problem is in patching itself. ZohaibIjaz plz read update

Comment: Indeed.  I'm just saying the thing you're trying to patch (`Calculator.add`) doesn't _actually exist_ - it _looks_ like you need to patch the entire `Calculator` function in some fashion.  But I also agree with @ZohaibIjaz, that it's not entirely clear in what way you want it to work after patching.

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly, from your update, it seems like you want to override `===` behaviour. You want to check equality to be evaluated after 2 sec.. You don't want to break any code then where is your code that you can change.

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz i could possible patch the `Calculator.add` sync function into async, by adding some additional `add(2).value()` function but still don't break the package

Comment: @procrastinator started bounty for you dude, i'm trying to write __http assertion__ plugin for [mjackson/expect](https://github.com/mjackson/expect) library

Comment: I guess you are trying to do something like that: https://github.com/mjackson/expect#extending-expect?

Comment: yes, but it's synchonous, simple [example](https://github.com/algolia/expect-jsx) of extending, i want to assert http results, like in [go version of http-asserion](https://github.com/gavv/httpexpect). Something like this `expect().GET("/fruits").toBeA('array');` or like this `expect().GET("/fruits").response().toBeA('array');`

Comment: As far as I know, it's not a good practice to perform unit tests in an network dependent context. You should better simulate the async call with a Stub (a test double). Stubs are a good way to get rid of the dependencies involved in the tested system.

Comment: There is no way this can run asynchronously `myCalc.add(2).value().equal(3);`, nor this: `expect().GET("/fruits").toBeA('array');` nor this: `expect().GET("/fruits").response().toBeA('array');`. This syntax can only be evaluated synchronously. You need a callback function at some place. @ZohaibIjaz had previously provided an answer based on this principle, which in my opinion was right on the spot. He deleted it. Yet it is the way to go.

Comment: I doubt that the Go module runs through the network. I guess that there is no "real" HTTP requests while the tests suite is running. I mean, the Go module and the tested program may be hosted at the same place and run in a synchronous way. That's a possibility that is worth to be considered.

Comment: Still there might be a solution, like converting callee function into callback or something, i tried something like [this](https://github.com/vko-online/expect-http/blob/master/index.js#L14-L23) but it;s totaly wrong and doesn't even work

Comment: Note that in that code the `expect` happens in a callback. Like I said, the only way to do anything with things that become available asynchronously, is to define a callback. You cannot use synchronous syntax, like a chain of method calls. You need somewhere to provide a callback function.

Comment: If there is a solution, it would still be a bad practice in my opinion. Indeed, how do you know if an error is related to the software or to the network? I would rather write a second test suite dedicated to the server side code. Anyway, I'm sorry but I'm not a candidate for this bounty :-|

Comment: There is no way to make a simple addition asynchronous (and it doesn't make sense anyway). What would you need this for?

Comment: @Bergi we have discussion with procrastinator above, read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you request a result by calling a chain of methods, like this:

```
a = myCalc.add(2).value();
```

or this:

```
myCalc.add(2).value().equal(3);
```

then there is ***no possibility*** to retrieve and use results that become available only asynchronously (i.e. later, after the statement has been evaluated). Note that *asynchronous* involves some event being put in the event queue. The currently executing code must finish first (i.e. until the call stack is empty), before that event can get processed.

The above syntax is useful for immediate evaluation only. In order to process asynchronous results you need to provide a call-back function somewhere for being informed about those results.

So with an asynchronous dependency in the `add` method, your code could provide a callback to the `add` method, which it would call when it has received the asynchronous result:

```
myAsyncCalc.add(2, function (added) {
    a = added.value();
});
```

Or, when using promises (which is really nice to work with), the `add` method would return an object to which you can assign the same call-back:

```
myAsyncCalc.add(2).then(function (added) {
    a = added.value();
});
```

Note that the callback function is not part of the currently executing code. It just is a function reference, that can be used at a later, asynchronous event for *calling you back*. But that will be part of a separate execution sequence, that only starts when the internal event queue has been processed and an event has been processed that triggered that execution sequence.

If this is not an acceptable solution, and you really need the former syntax to somehow take an asynchronous produced result into account, then you are without hope: it is not possible, because that really represents *synchronous* code execution.

#### Wrapping your Object

You write that you cannot modify the content of the package, but can only extend it.

One way to do that is to make use of [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).
The idea is that you trap a reference to the `add` method, and return 
your own adapted version of the method, which can optionally still call the original method.
See the above referenced MDN article for examples.

#### Calling HTTP request Synchronously

If you really want to write code like this:

```
a = myCalc.add(2).value();
```

even when the implementation of `add` performs an HTTP request, then you could have a look at making the HTTP request synchronously. But it should be noted that this is considered bad practice.

#### Code Example

Here is code that performs the addition in three ways:

- unmodified (synchronous)
- with an asynchronous HTPP call
- with a synchronous HTTP call

For the two modified versions, a proxy pattern is used. For the asynchronous example, a call back is used using the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) pattern.

Code:

```js
// code in module is not modified
function Calculator(value){
    return {
        add: function(value2){
            return {
                value: function(){
                    return value + value2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// standard object creation
var myCalc = new Calculator(1); // initialized with 1

// Create a proxy for the above object, which will expose 
// an asynchronous version of the "add" method. Note that the
// "myCalc" object is not modified.
var myCalcHttpAsync = new Proxy(myCalc, {
    get: function(myCalc, name) {
        if (name !== 'add') return myCalc[name]; // pass-through
        return function(value2) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                // Define some url
                var url = 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2';
                // Perform HTTP request
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                // Define call back for when response becomes available
                request.onload = function() {
                    if (request.readyState !== 4) return; 
                    // When async task notifies it has finished:
                    // call the original "add" method and notify those 
                    // waiting for the promise to get resolved
                    resolve(myCalc.add(value2));
                };
                // `true` as third argument makes the request asynchronous
                request.open('GET', url, true);
                request.send(null); 
            });
        };
    }
});

// Create another, alternative proxy for demonstrating 
// synchronous HTTP call:
var myCalcHttpSync = new Proxy(myCalc, {
    get: function(myCalc, name) {
        if (name !== 'add') return myCalc[name]; // pass-through
        return function(value2) {
            // Define some url
            var url = 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2';
            // Perform HTTP request
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            // `false` as third argument makes the request synchronous
            request.open('GET', url, false);
            // code execution "hangs" here until response arrives  
            request.send(null); 
            // process response...
            var data = request.responseText;
            // .. and return the value
            return myCalc.add(value2);
        };
    }
});

// I/O

var std = document.getElementById('std');
var async = document.getElementById('async');
var sync = document.getElementById('sync');

// 1. Standard 
std.textContent = myCalc.add(2).value();

// 2. Asynchronous HTTP
myCalcHttpAsync.add(2).then(function (added) {
    // This needs to happen in a callback, otherwise it would be synchronous.
    async.textContent = added.value();
});

// 3. Synchronous HTTP 
sync.textContent = myCalcHttpSync.add(2).value();
```

```html
Unmodified result: <span id="std">waiting...</span><br>
Result after asynchronous HTTP call: <span id="async">waiting...</span><br>
Result after synchronous HTTP call: <span id="sync">waiting...</span><br>
```

Comment: The async.proxy version looks good altho it was not what i was expecting, anyway +1. Hope we'll see some other interesting solutions

Comment: What are you expecting? Do you see why code like `myCalc.add(2).value().equal(3);` can impossibly incorporate an asynchronous result?

Comment: I was wondering if there is something like `function value(){arguments.callee.name}` that we can get the name of function, and use inside promise

Comment: At that location `arguments.callee.name` will render `"value"`. What would you want to happen with that value? Note that you will only get at that expression when you actually call `value(...)`, and at that moment what would be the use of knowing the name of that function? Certainly not to call it a second time...

Comment: I thought about patching all props(exported funcs) of  `myCalc.add(2)` and call the one i get from _arguments.callee.name_

Comment: `arguments.callee.name` only has a value in a function call. In which function would you place it? I don't see how `arguments.callee.name` can be of any use for your question. As I wrote above, it will return the name of the running function. As it is already running, why would you still need a reference to it? Concerning the patching: that is exactly what a proxy does. In the implementation I propose, only the `add` property is altered, but you can alter any property.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using promise.

Here is a link to jsbin where you can execute the code.

http://jsbin.com/qadobor/edit?html,js,console,output

```
function Calculator(value) {
  return {
    add: function(value2) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(
          function() {
            resolve(value + value2);
          }, 2000);
      });
    }
  };
}

var myCalc = new Calculator(1); // initialized with 1

myCalc.add(2).then(function(ans){
  // this callback will be called after 2 seconds after promise resolve.
  console.log(ans);
});
```

Comment: btw, this totally doesn't cover the OP question, plz update or remove it

Comment: sure, kindly tag me when you find some better solution.

Comment: Seems this solution is only way to go, sorry i didn't realize the impossibility of my expectations, so +1 for the working idea